# D3 what is the difference between these two way of data binding?

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I wonder why these two code snippets will render different results when there are existing DOM elements in the body? When I have only one "dog" element in the body
old the results is - dog. 20 30 2 32 4 1.

However, if I have 10 dog p elements(which is larger than the dataset length), then the html will just give me 10 dogs p element, with nothing updated.

The 2nd code snippet render the right results as I expect. Updating the exiting p elements with dataset value.

From my understanding, `enter` will compare the existing DOM elements with dataset values and update the DOM elements according to new data. Why the first one does not work as expected?

```
<body>
    <p>dog.</p>
    <p>dog.</p>
    <p>dog.</p>
    <p>dog.</p>
    <p>dog.</p>
</body>
```

First one:

```
var dataset = [10,20,30,2,32,4,1];

d3.select("body")
            .selectAll("p")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d){return(d);});
```

Second one:

```
var dataset = [10,20,30,2,32,4,1];

    elements = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
                .data(dataset)

    elements
           .enter()
           .append("p");

    elements.text(function(d){return(d);});
```

Comment: The first one will add the text within the appended "p" element and the second will enter the text directly into the "elements".

Comment: Thanks MattSizzle. Can you please explain it with more details about why the 2nd code will replace the existing p element texts, but the first one wont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet operates only on the enter selection, the second snippet also on the update selection. So if there are existing elements that are matched by the data, the first snippet won't change them while the second will.

The `.data()` call returns the update selection and you get the enter and exit selections by calling `.enter()` and `.exit()` on it. As you are not doing that in the second snippet when setting `.text()`, the operation is performed on the update selection (i.e. the elements that are already there and have been matched by data *plus* the elements from the enter selection for which you have appended new elements just before).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So when I call `elements.enter().append("p")`, I was thinking it has already get the enter selections, so it will "pass" the selection to elements and it will carry on to `text()` function? Can u please point out where I'm wrong?

Comment: When you call `elements.enter().append("p")` you operate on the enter selection. When you call `elements.append("p")`, you operate on the update selection.

Comment: Got it. However, the data I passed into 1st code snippet is number but the existing DOM elements are "dogs", they shouldn't be treated as MATCHED by enter selection... d3 doesn't take deeper look into the data inside p element??

Comment: No. The default key function is the index, i.e. the first datum is matched to the first element, the second to the second and so on, regardless of what the data actually is.

Comment: According to your comments, I am trying to do this - I assume I'm operating UPDATE selection, however it turns out the results are nested.  
   `var ele = d3.select('body')
   .selectAll('p')
   .data(dataset);
                  ele.append('p')
   .text(function(d) {return d;})
   .style('color', 'red');`

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say that the results are nested.

Comment: The results are like `dog.
10


dog.
20


dog.
30


dog.
2


dog.
32` which means the old DOM elements are not replaced by the new data values.

Comment: You're appending a new `p` element for everything in the update selection. You're not replacing anything.

Comment: I tried this too - `ele.enter(). append('p') .text(function(d) {return d;}) .style('color', 'red');` which works well do you know why?

Comment: There you are operating on the enter selection. See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles) for more details on selections.